# Java: Set file permissions to several users

Tags: java, xml, file, java-io, r.java-file

For a little application that I'm writing there's a file.xml which is a database.

When the file.xml is created with:

```
File xmlDB = new File(newYear + ".xml");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newYear+".xml", "UTF-8");
String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><economato> </economato>";
writer.println(header);
```

then I can set permissions with

```
xmlDB.setwReadable()
XML.setWritable()
```

but I've understood that with these primitives I can set the permission either for the owner of for everyone. Instead how can I set these permissions for 2 or 3 people (of given their username they use to log in  into the server?)??

I'd need to know this for Linux but overall for Windows.
Am I supposed to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Windows prompt command");
```

to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add permisions to groups and then add those users that you want to that groups

```
   //using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 777
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
    //add owners permission
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    //add group permissions
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
    //add others permissions
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get("/Users/pankaj/run.sh"), perms);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about doing that in WINDOWS instead?

Comment: In windows you have group of users as well. If you consider the answer rememeber to finish the post